# Can "somewhere" sometimes be a substitute for "sometime"?

Tags: semantics

Here is an example of an author appearing to do just that. "It seems, no matter my intentions, my other 4 babies were 'off the boob' (yes, I'm sometimes known for my less-than PC vernacular) somewhere between 4-6 months."  *Caterflies & Butterpillars*, E. Tyler Rowan (2012)

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat colloquial, but common, usage for *approximately*. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/somewhere) lists it as the third definition of *somewhere* as an adverb:

> : in the vicinity of : **APPROXIMATELY** → usually used with *about*, *around*,
> or *between*

with examples:
*somewhere about nine o'clock*
*costs somewhere around ten dollars*